# npm doesn't work because of some proxy issue but i don't use a proxy

Tags: javascript, npm, debian, nvm, termux

npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/boostrap failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-05-28T23_16_12_211Z-debug.log

I thought it was Termux, but i use a like-Debian inside and it shows the same error. By the way, it is the first time that I use nvm.